Microsoft Graph. Move conversation between Groups?
We try to migrate  from Exchange PublicFolders to Office 365 Groups.
Out public folder contains set of email messages, and special program scan this folder, and process emails. If email was processes successfully - it moved to Archive public folder, if not - to Failed public folder.
Now we try to make some similar way with Office 365 Groups.
The group does not contains the email message, it contains only conversations.
Is there the way to move conversation to another group?

The equivalent to a Post in a Public folder is a Post in a Group https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/post-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. However the ability to move, copy and do any sort of folder ops in Groups is absent in the API even though the UI can do it.  If its only Apps that are accessing the folder then a Shared Mailbox maybe a better option.
